# What does the "$T$" superscript mean on vector?

Tags: special-relativity, vectors, notation

My relativity book defines the "worldline" of a system as:

\begin{equation}
x(\tau)=(x^0(\tau),x^1(\tau),x^2(\tau),x^3(\tau))^T
\end{equation}

I often see velocities written in the same form: $U=(0,u^2,0)^T$

What does the "$T$" superscript mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The $T$ stands for "transposed". The vectors $x(\tau)$ and $U$ are column vectors, but they are printed as transposed row vectors to save space.

Comment: So that's why the superindex is removed once the vector is expressed as $\begin{pmatrix} x^0(\tau) \\ x^i(\tau) \end{pmatrix}$